# Построение кратчайшего маршрута через несколько точек (JavaScript, Яндекс карты)

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, графы, любой-язык, поиск-пути

Стоит задача сделать программу для построения маршрута доставки товара, которая будет выдавать самый короткий маршрут от пункта отправления до пункта прибытия, проходя через несколько промежуточных точек. Я собираюсь использовать яндекс карты. В итоге должен получиться аналог этого сервиса: http://logist.ennu.ru. У яндекса есть пример построения маршрута по нескольким точкам https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/router . Автоматической реализации выбора порядка точек маршрута для создания самого короткого маршрута в API не нашел (хотя может плохо искал). Поэтому собираюсь написать свое приложение на JS, которое будет определять порядок следования по точкам для создания кратчайшего маршрута.

**Пунктом отправления и прибытия может являться один и тот же адрес.**

Есть ли готовые реализации того, что мне нужно? Какой алгоритм построения маршрутов лучше всего использовать (реализация будет на js) с учетом того, что возможно конечной точкой будет точка отправления?

**Update 1 Алгоритм Дейкстры мне не подходит, так как мне нужно посетить все узлы в обязательном порядке пройдя минимальное расстояние.**

Comment: Первое, что в голову приходит https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Алгоритм_Дейкстры

Comment: @КириллЖелнов разве он является оптимальным решением, если мне нужно вернуться в точку отправления?

Comment: а не проще исходный код того сервиса глянуть?

Comment: @Jean-Claude может быть и проще, только я там ничего не понял :(